# FileSizeLimitExceededException while uploading file greater than allowed limit

Tags: java, exception, jetty, multipartform-data, apache-commons-fileupload

```
public static void parseUpload(HttpServletRequest request) throws AttachmentException
{
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))
{
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setSizeThreshold(10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB
    ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    uploader.setSizeMax(3 * 1024 * 1024); // allowed file size
    uploader.setFileSizeMax(3 * 1024 * 1024);

    List<FileItem> items;
    try
    {
        items = uploader.parseRequest(request); // throws exception
        for (FileItem fileItem : items)
        {

        }
    }
    catch (FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException e)
    {
        // catch block 1 (stack trace printed)
        throw new AttachmentException(e); // This is being caught in JSP
    }
    catch (FileUploadException e)
    {
        // catch block 2
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // catch block 3
    }
}
}
```

I am calling this function from a JSP and things work just fine when I'm uploading a file with size less than 3 MBs.

> **The moment I upload a file with size greater than 3 MBs the catch block catches the exception but web server returns 502. The application is deployed on JETTY.**

The application hangs for a moment and the amount of delay is proportional to the size of attachment.

Exception trace:

```
parseUpload <@> FileSizeLimitExceededException with error message : The field urlname exceeds its maximum permitted size of 3145728 bytes. 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl$FileItemStreamImpl$1.raiseError(FileUploadBase.java:789)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.checkLimit(LimitedInputStream.java:78) 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:137)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:100)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:70)
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:347) 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:115)
parseUpload(UploadUtils.java:255)
```

> **It seems that however the exception is caught the file is still getting parsed or some other exception has been thrown again.**

I have gone through similar posts but none provides the exact reason for this and how to handle this case. Please provide some help here.

Comment: I do not understand. The server has been told the file is too big via the `FileSizeLimitExceededException `. The client has been told via the 502 response code. What exactly are you expecting, and why?

Comment: @EJP when exception has been caught then why should server return 502. It should stop processing data the moment it encounters the attachment size has increased the allowed limit but the application hangs.

Comment: Why shouldn't the server return 502? The upload is still too big. What *should* the server return? I repeat. What exactly are you excpecting, and why?

Comment: I am re-throwing the exception (catch block 1) and catching the same in my JSP and showing an error message, which is the desired behavior but instead the application hangs. Irrespective of error code returned by the server the application should not hang and timeout. Do you really think this is how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: I don't see anything about rethrowing and catching the exception in the JSP page in your question. Try posting a *complete* question next time.

Comment: But you do see the application getting hang in this scenario, which is the real problem here.